# How to remove dynamically created textboxes in tabcontrol in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

I'v created a program that dynamically creates text-boxes according to the number selected from the combobox. The problem is that when I change the number from a big number to a smaller one the text-boxes keep the same ex(10 then 3).
[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8iiV.png) 
 I tried entering a code to remove the text-boxes before the *for loop but it didn't work.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        num = ComboBox1.Text
        Dim tp As TabPage = tabControl1.TabPages(0)
        *For i = 1 To num
            Dim TB As New TextBox
            TB.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(60, 20)
            TB.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("arial", 20)
            TB.Location = New Point(10, i * 40)
            TB.Name = "tbt" & i
            Select Case i
                Case 1 To 5
                    TB.Location = New Point(10, i * 45)
                Case 6 To 10
                    Dim i2 As Integer = i - 5
                    TB.Location = New Point(80, i2 * 45)
            End Select
            tp.Controls.Add(TB)
        Next
    End Sub
```

note: I tried this method without tabcontrol it worked perfectly.

```
     Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
            _Textboxes.ForEach(New Action(Of TextBox)(AddressOf Controls.Remove))
            _Textboxes.Clear()
            num = ComboBox1.Text
            ...
                End Select
                Controls.Add(TB)
                _Textboxes.Add(TB)
            Next
```

Comment: You are only adding controls, you arent checking of there is already a `"tbt" & i` control and not removing the excess controls, ifs any.  After not adding 1,2,3 you need to remove and dispose of those with a name beyond 4.  You still need to turn on Option Strict, by the way.  You might also consider something like a single column DGV or maybe a ListView rather than controls.

Comment: all i need is to put this program in a tabcontrol and make it work https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KTYPbMk_RbR0pfkvXdaKIoyagxNt5c6n7QtRwycYg2o                     note: this program is working fine without tabcontrol